# Checkstyle unable to parse configuration stream - Document is invalid: no grammar found Error

Tags: java, gradle, checkstyle

I am trying out checkstyle with gradle and I keep getting the error,

```
Execution failed for task ':checkstyleMain'.
> Unable to create a Checker: unable to read /root/gradleTest/config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml - unable to parse configuration stream - Document is invalid: no grammar found.:1:8
```

I tried pretty much every solution I found online for similar problems but I keep getting the same issue. 
 My build.gradle file,

> apply plugin: 'java' apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
>
> repositories {   mavenCentral() }

And I am using the sun_checks.xml file avaialble here : https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/sun_checks.xml

Any ideas on how this issue can be resolved?

EDIT:

Solution.

It turns out I was using the wrong file. Checkstyle was looking for `config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml` but my file was `config/checkstyle.xml`. That was the error

Comment: Which file are you using: `/root/gradleTest/config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml` or `sun_checks.xml`?

Comment: I am using the `sun_checks` file in that location.  I have named it `checkstyle` as that is the default.

Comment: Make sure you have the right version of the file. It must match the Checkstyle version. [Here](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/checkstyle-7.3/src/main/resources/sun_checks.xml)'s the URL, modify it to fit your version.

Comment: Thank you for the help. It turns out I was using the wrong file.  Checkstyle was looking for `config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml` but my file was `config/checkstyle.xml`. That was the error.